# SQL Server 7.0 from 2000, DTS corruption of view definition

Tags: sql-server, dts

As a step in the process of eliminating remote servers and upgrading to SQL server 2017, I'm trying to move a database from 2000 to a staging server running 7.0 It should be a simple DTS task, using the DTS wizard.  Data transfer works without problems. Simple views based only on tables transfer without problems.

But after correctly transferring the view

```
 unique_group_not_last
```

it gets overwritten by

```
 unique_group_with_last
```

... leaving me with, in the target database, one view, named unique_group_with_last, but actually implementing unique_group_not_last. It's renamed the previous view, instead of adding the next view.

Did this use to be normal for SQL Server DTS? If so, what were you supposed to do instead? Was there something like an 8 character identifier limit for DTS?

I can use other tools or techniques -- I can't change the source or the target, but I can connect a laptop to the subnet, and any set of client tools is possible.

15 years ago, how did you make this work?

Comment: You say you're moving *to* SQL Server 7.0, however, SQL Server 2000 was version 8; that implies you're downgrading, not upgrading? Why are you going backwards?

Comment: Because the staging server is only SS7.0.  It was only used for staging, and never qualified for an upgrade, even to 2000. Now its going to be deleted-- but not until the live process is replaced.

Comment: But if you're aiming to get to SQL Server 2017 then going from 2000 to 7.0 is the wrong way. Either way, 2000 has been long out of support (and 7.0 even longer). You would likely be better off scripting out anything you need rather than relying on tools that haven't been updated or supported for 7-10 years.

Comment: You're basically creating problems for yourself that shouldn't be part of this process at all. Assuming your database is too big for Express, if you look around you can probably still find downloads for the Developer Edition of SQL Server 2008 R2 (the last version to support compat level 80), upgrade to compat level 100 (reviewing what might break), then go directly to SQL Server 2017 (which supports compat level 100). Going from lower to higher versions has the significant benefit of allowing you to restore from backups, rather than having to transfer data.